# iOS Universal Link not working on Second Attempt

Tags: node.js, ios-universal-links

I am trying to integrate with universal Link in my project with Ouath2,
If user is trying to Login with Facebook in my app,using oauth2 library I am generating token and If it success then I am forming Universal link and in my nodejs endpoint I am redirecting with that Universal link.
First time It works as expected in the sense already my app installed on the device it opens.
Second time I did same thing but that time also my app was installed but it is not opening the app instead it was showing PopUp like **Open with App store**

Actually it should open the App.
Can someone help me to figure out the issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you add the flow of your app,so after generating the link you open it with Safari, and after authentication you want to redirect back to app ? Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes exactly correct.

Comment: Why don't you use `SFSafariViewController` instead. It's more appropriate for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is it work in my case?If yes then I will go for that

Comment: It's perfect for what you are trying to do. I just implemented this in one app and Universal Links are pain in the neck. Also, Universal Links are not the correct approach. I switched to `SFSafariViewController` and it's way easy.

Comment: Okay Tejas,Thank you so much for the info.

Comment: Anytime, feel free to ask any issue you face regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing is the expected behavior. Universal Links will only succeed in opening an app when they are tapped on by the user. They cannot be programmatically triggered.